# Decoding hex string gives me garbage

Tags: python, hex

I have a hex string:

`12104c06134e5709140f104f02521b0a0442020c4d070b184f4815541f0800484e1e0241061d064d540b0a020210194510164d4f3a005343004e430e1e1d0a524612171b0117001b0e45431c0c1d160a520d11744e19061a114d0e55174f084e543714050b174353541b48070e000e4d`

if you're curious, that I simply want to decode into readable text (though this a crypto problem so the decoded text will still appear to be nonsense, but nonhexnonsense). To do this, I have saved the above message into the variable msg. I then performed this operation:

```
msg.decode('hex')
```

However, when I print the value, I get some characters, a bunch of weird squares, and text fragmented on multiple lines. What's going on?

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: Well, I'm not well versed enough in hex conversions to give you an exact representation of what I expect, but basically a string of english characters and spaces, some uppercase some lowercase.

Comment: When I convert your hex here (http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) I get the same result as you.  Either the hex doesn't represent what you think it does, or you generated an incorrect hex string.

Comment: Though python is quite powerful, I don't think that there is a function `solve_crypto_riddle`.

Comment: Many of the values in the hex string do not decode into ASCII or utf-8 characters, so if printed it will be unreadable non-character garbage mixed with a few regular characters after decoding.

Comment: Even `binascii.unhexlify(your_String)` returns the same answer as you're getting.

Comment: It would equate to 896 bits, which seems an odd key size... (But 112 is half a sha224...) but apart from that - no idea.

Comment: If you filter alphas and digits, you get `'LNWORBMOHTHNAMTEMOSCNCRFECRtNMUONT7CSTHM'`, but not sure if that's any use either...

Comment: If you add a constant value between 32 and 40 to the value represented by each 2 characters, you get a text consisting of letters, numbers and common symbols and interpunction, but no exotic unicode characters. For example, with a shift of 39 you get `97s-:u~0;67v)yB1+i)3t.2?vo<{F/'ouE)h-D-t{21))7@l7=tva'zj'uj5ED1ym9>B(>'B5ljC3D=1y48›u@-A8t5|>v/u{^;,2>jz{Bo.5'5t`. You said that the result would still be encrypted. So, does this look more like what you were expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you think some [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) data is stored in that hex string.  If that is the case, every 2 characters in the hex string represent one byte of ASCII text.  If that were the case, you could do this to decode it:

```
>>> a = "12104c06134e5709140f104f02521b0a0442020c4d070b184f4815541f0800484e1e0241061d064d540b0a020210194510164d4f3a005343004e430e1e1d0a524612171b0117001b0e45431c0c1d160a520d11744e19061a114d0e55174f084e543714050b174353541b48070e000e4d"
>>> bytes = [a[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
>>> s_decoded = [chr(int(c,16)) for c in bytes]
>>> ''.join(s_decoded)
'\x12\x10L\x06\x13NW\t\x14\x0f\x10O\x02R\x1b\n\x04B\x02\x0cM\x07\x0b\x18OH\x15T\x1f\x08\x00HN\x1e\x02A\x06\x1d\x06MT\x0b\n\x02\x02\x10\x19E\x10\x16MO:\x00SC\x00NC\x0e\x1e\x1d\nRF\x12\x17\x1b\x01\x17\x00\x1b\x0eEC\x1c\x0c\x1d\x16\nR\r\x11tN\x19\x06\x1a\x11M\x0eU\x17O\x08NT7\x14\x05\x0b\x17CST\x1bH\x07\x0e\x00\x0eM'
```

But, as you can see, most of these characters are "non-printable" characters (i.e. their ASCII values don't code some human readable character like 'A' or 'd').  Here is an example of decoding a hex string which DOES contain printable ASCII characters:

```
>>> a2 = "43616c6562"
>>> bytes2 = [a2[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(a2),2)]
>>> bytes2
['43', '61', '6c', '65', '62']
>>> ''.join([chr(int(c,16)) for c in bytes2])
'Caleb'
>>>
```

Comment: Uh, why not simply write `'43616c6562'.decode('hex')` ?

Comment: This way was more explicit as to what is actually going on.